# injectivity of pushout?

Tags: gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory

We have the following pushout diagram:
$$\begin{array}{ccc} \langle X, Y \rangle & \xrightarrow{\alpha} & \mathbb{Z}_a \ast \mathbb{Z}_b \ast \mathbb{Z}_c \ast \mathbb{Z}_d \\ \downarrow \scriptsize{\beta} && \downarrow \scriptsize{g} \\ \mathbb{Z}_e & \xrightarrow{f} & G\end{array}$$
Suppose that $\alpha$ is injective, and $\beta$ maps $X,Y$ to $1\in \mathbb{Z}_e$. ($\mathbb{Z}_n$ means the cyclic group of order $n$.)

I wonder that in which cases, $f$ is injective.
For any positive integers $a,b,c,d,e \geq 2$? Otherwise, only for relative prime or distinct prime $a,b,c,d,e$?

(I found that if $\phi$ is injective, then $\psi$ is injective in "adhesive" categories. The category of abelian groups is adhesive, and the category of groups isn't. I also wonder which subcategory of groups are adhesive. )
$$\begin{array}{ccc}A & \xrightarrow{\phi} & B \\ \downarrow && \downarrow \\ C & \xrightarrow{\psi} & D\end{array}$$.

In the category of groups, there is a counterexample:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/601463/a-monomorphism-of-groups-which-is-not-universal

I can change my diagram similarly to the above counterexample:
$$\begin{array}{ccc}\mathbb{Z} & \xrightarrow{\alpha'} & (\mathbb{Z}_a \ast \mathbb{Z}_b \ast \mathbb{Z}_c \ast \mathbb{Z}_d)/\langle X=Y \rangle \\ \downarrow \scriptsize{\beta'} && \downarrow \scriptsize{g'} \\ \mathbb{Z}_e & \xrightarrow{f} & G\end{array}$$
$\alpha'(1)=X$, any words in $X,Y$ are nontrivial in $\mathbb{Z}_a \ast \mathbb{Z}_b \ast \mathbb{Z}_c \ast \mathbb{Z}_d$, and $\beta'$ is surjective. Then, $\alpha'$ is also injective. For instance, fix $Y=1_a 1_b 1_c 1_d$ with a generator $1_n$ of $\mathbb{Z}_n$. May $f$ not be a monomorphism?

Comment: The pushout of a one-to-one map in the category of sets is one-to-one. In the category of groups, my guess is that you have to add the free compositions. So I would be surprised that $f$ is not one-to-one.

Comment: What has this got to do with topos theory ?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi I found that the above injectivity holds in any topos (toposes are adhesive). I cannot understand what topos is, but I think it may provide some answer. If topos theory has nothing to do with my question, sorry. Then, tell me. I will subtract it.

Comment: @PhilippeGaucher What does it mean to add the free compositions in the category of groups? Could you explain it in detail?

Comment: @qkqh I've learnt something today, I could not imagine that there would be a counterexample. In my mind, a group is a one-object category, and the pushout must contain all possible compositions.

Answer (score 2):

The first exercise in Serre’s book *[Trees](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-61856-7)* spells this out (I’ve corrected a missing “normal”):

Let $f_1\colon A \to G_1$ and $f_2\colon A \to G_2$ be two homomorphisms and let $G$ be their pushout. We define subgroups $A^n$, $G^n_1$ and $G^n_2$ of $A$, $G_1$ and $G_2$ recursively by the following conditions:

- $A^1 = \{1\}, \qquad G^1_1=\{1\}, \qquad G^1_2 = \{1\}$
- $A^n = $ normal subgroup of $A$ generated by $f^{-1}_1(G^{n-1}_1)$ and $f^{-1}_2(G^{n-1}_2)$
- $G^n_i = $ normal subgroup of $G_i$ generated by $f_i(A^n)$.

Let $A^\infty$, $G^\infty_i$ be the unions of the $A^n$, $G^n_i$, respectively. Show that $f_i$ defines an *injection* $A/A^\infty \to G_i/G^\infty_i$ and that $G$ may be identified with the amalgam of $G_1/G^\infty_1$ and $G_2/G^\infty_2$ along $A/A^\infty$.

It follows (using the results of no. 1.2 in *Trees*) that the kernel of $A\to G$ is $A^\infty$ and that the kernel of $G_i \to G$ is $G_i^\infty$.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Applying the theory to my lower diagram ($f_1:=\alpha', f_2=\beta'$), $A^n=A^\infty=e\mathbb{Z}, G_1^n=G_1^\infty=\langle \langle X^e \rangle \rangle, G_2^n=G_2^\infty=1$ for any $n>1$, and so $A/A^\infty=\mathbb{Z}_e \to G_1/G_1^\infty=G$ is injective. Hence, $f$ is alway injective!! Wow! Could you tell me some references to study it?

Comment: I want to insert missing subindex "1" on the codomain of $f_1$ in your answer, but I couldn't. I should fix at least 6 characters.

Comment: I've found that it is a book. However, I cannot find the nomality condition that you've modified.

Comment: In the exercise as written Serre does not say that $A^n$ and $G^n_i$ should be  the *normal* subgroups generated by the conditions above. I spent a full day confused about this;  I seem to recall that one family of subgroups was likely normal, but couldn't see any reason for the other family to be normal.

Comment: also, I really love *Trees,* I think it's a great introduction to a subject I like a lot.

Comment: I remember getting stumped by this omission of _normal_ as well. Serre does say _dist._ (for _distingué_) in the French original so it was lost in (the generally excellent) translation.

Comment: Yes, we need the normality condition only to ensure that $A/A^\infty, G_i/G_i^\infty$ become groups. But, sadly, my first comment was wrong; I do not know what $f_1^{-1}(\langle\langle X^e \rangle\rangle)$ is. (On the above counterexample, $\langle\langle h^n \rangle\rangle$ is the whole group.) That's what I've wanted to know: $\{X^n\} \cap \langle\langle X^e \rangle\rangle_{G_1}$. I'm back to square one.